# Adding quotations around words preceding a colon in Python

Tags: python, find-replace

I am learning Python (python3) and am working with a text file containing semi-JSON format. It is not full JSON because the "keys" are not surrounded by quotes. I am looking to programmatically add quotes around all of these key names. My plan was to "open" this file and parse each "line" as an individual string.

**From:**

> key_name: { another_key: "somevalue", second_key: "anotherval" }

**Into:**

> "key_name": { "another_key": "somevalue", "second_key": "anotherval" }

I'm sure regex would be the ideal way to do this - for the sake of learning I have been using arrays...

I have some code that works partially, but not all of the keys get parentheses placed around them.

```
str = "this is: a string: testing testing: blah blah more: test: hereis: test:"

cp_str = list(str[::-1])

skip = False
find_end = False
for step in range(len(cp_str) - 1):
  if skip:    
    skip = False
    continue

  if cp_str[step] == ':':    
    cp_str.insert(step + 1, '"')
    skip = True
    find_end = True

  if not skip and find_end and not(ord(cp_str[step].lower()) > 95 and ord(cp_str[step].lower()) < 95+26):    
    cp_str.insert(step, '"')
    skip = True
    find_end = False

print(''.join(cp_str[::-1]))
```

**Outputs:**

> this is: a string": testing "testing": blah blah "more":
>   "test": "hereis": "test":

Any tips or help on the best ways to tackle this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example code `this is: a string` isn't related to JSON much at all--there aren't any commas or brackets, so I don't think testing against it proves anything about the ability of a program to convert non-quoted keys in an almost-JSON file to quoted keys. It's not really clear to me what the output is even supposed to be. I recommend sticking to your top example.

Comment: Yes, technically you're right? However, my idea was to parse each line of the file individually and thus am dealing with a "string".

Comment: Actually, your top example isn't valid JSON either, since there's a `key_name` floating in space. I recommend clarifying what your input really is, otherwise it's a bit futile to chase after arbitrary edge cases.

Comment: I don’t think this is the best way to deal with JSON format. I would instead import the json package and simply use json.dumps()

Comment: It's assumed that OP doesn't have access to writing the JSON and has to deal with reading invalid JSON. `JSON.loads` can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using regex to handle structured formats. It will almost always mis-handle certain corner cases.

Since your input is valid YAML, you can install [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), load the input as YAML, and dump the data structure as JSON instead:

```
import yaml
import json
s = 'key_name: { another_key: "somevalue", second_key: "anotherval" }'
print(json.dumps(yaml.load(s)))
```

This outputs:

```
{"key_name": {"another_key": "somevalue", "second_key": "anotherval"}}
```

Comment: This seems like a good option. I haven't used YAML much but will check this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While the pattern `([{,]\s*)([^"]*?)(\s*:\s*)` isn't going to cover all corner cases, it should work fine for basic JSON content.

Example usage:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = '{ another_key: "somevalue", second_key: "anotherval" }'
>>> repl_fn = lambda x: f'{x.group(1)}"{x.group(2)}"{x.group(3)}'
>>> re.sub(r'([{,]\s*)([^"]*?)(\s*:\s*)', repl_fn, data)
'{ "another_key": "somevalue", "second_key": "anotherval" }'
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the `"` inside the regexp.

Comment: You're right. I updated the code via copy-paste. Fixed. My intent was to allow keys that are already quoted correctly to be left alone.